# Please try using smaller versions of images

Tags: discussion, images

Recently I asked [this question on global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101439/132564). The problem is when users upload huge photos to illustrate something they usually don't need very high resolution - for example, it might be a photo of a sink and it doesn't need to be 2000K by 1500K and weigh 700 kilobytes - it can be much smaller and will still look good. Downloading huge pictures is a problem for many users.

[Turns out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-pho/101446#101446) (thanks to [user Jeremy Banks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300/jeremy-banks) for that answer!) imgur.com allows to downscale images automatically by appending letter `l` between the name and the extension.

So you upload an image and you get a link like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xulw9.jpg and when you insert `l` you get https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xulw9l.jpg (notice `l` before `.jpg`) and that automatically makes imgur.com serve a smaller version of the image that weighs much less.

I kindly ask all users who add pictures to use this feature unless of course you need that super high resolution to illustrate some super fine details.

Comment: Noting how "l" is also used in the 5-digit hash. That's gonna suck when they run out of namespace and need to go to a 6th digit.  They'll have to code a special exception to never generate a hash ending in "l".

Answer (score 5):

Good find about the `l`.

I wonder if something could be done to insert the `l` automatically?

I've just worked out that `l` actually stands for "large thumbnail". You can get smaller images by appending `m` (for "medium") and `s` (for "small") as well.

Comment: Sure. There's a feature request on global meta. It shouldn't be that hard to render appropriate HTML by SO engine - like insert a small version inline and provide a link to a full size version. I guess once it gets enough upvotes the team implements it.

Comment: Btw I made a separate explicit feature request for that - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107927/132564